# Rotating image decentres image using janmuller library

Tags: android, rotation, crop

I am using janmuller android library to perform rotation of an image . On rotating it 90 degrees to the left or right the image is rotated , however it gets de centred on the screen . This is the code I have used from janmuller library

```
    public void onRotateRight(View v) {
    mBitmap = Util.rotateImage(mBitmap, 90);
    RotateBitmap rotateBitmap = new RotateBitmap(mBitmap);
    mImageView.setImageRotateBitmapResetBase(rotateBitmap, true);
    mRunFaceDetection.run();
    }
```

This is the rotateImage function

```
    public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap src, float degree) {
    // create new matrix
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // setup rotation degree
    matrix.postRotate(degree);
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: Please post some pictures somewhere to demonstrate.

Comment: That is only one picture. We need at least two pictures. One before rotation and one after.

Comment: In `onRotateRight` i miss how you initiate mBitmap. Please show. Is mImageView a normal ImageView?

Comment: mImageView is a CropImageView supplied by the library I have used

Comment: Please fullfiill my request.

Comment: private CropImageView mImageView;

Comment: N here is the CropImageView is a class defined in the library as follows

Comment: Repeat: `i miss how you initiate mBitmap. Please show.`

Comment: Please don't put code in comments as this is unreadable. Just make an extra code block in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onRotateRight(View v) {
mBitmap = Util.rotateImage(mBitmap, 90);
RotateBitmap rotateBitmap = new RotateBitmap(mBitmap);
mImageView.setImageRotateBitmapResetBase(rotateBitmap, true);
mRunFaceDetection.run();
}
```

I wonder why you have so much code. Especially i wonder that after having used rotateImage() on the bitmap you dont put it back in the imageview. There is so much code with rotate (why is that needed?) and reset base (what does that?) that it is difficult to say who is to blame when things go wrong. Better try with a normal ImageView first before you blame janmuller. More like this:

```
public void onRotateRight(View v) {
mBitmap = Util.rotateImage(mBitmap, 90);

mImageView.setImageBitMap(mBitmap);
}
```

That should be enough to test;

The function rotateImage() looks ok.